# _mm512_mask_i32logather_pd not available for GNU compiler

Tags: gcc, intrinsics, icc, avx512

I have a codebase which contains AVX512 intrinsic instructions and was build using intel compiler. I am trying to run the same thing using GNU compiler. While compiling the code with **-mavx512f** flag using gcc, I am getting declaration error only for some AVX512 instructions like **_mm512_mask_i32logather_pd**.

**Standalone Implementation**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main() {
__m512d set = _mm512_undefined_pd();
__mmask16 msk = 42440;
__m512i v_index = _mm512_set_epi32(64,66,70,96,98,100,102,104,106,112,114,116,118,120,124,256);
int scale = 8;
int count_size = 495*4;
float *src_ptr = (float*)malloc(count_size*sizeof(float));
__m512 out_512 = (__m512)_mm512_mask_i32logather_pd(set, msk, v_index, (float*)src_ptr, _MM_SCALE_8);
return 0;
}
```

After running this standalone implementation for the function through gcc I am getting the error as

```
error: ‘_mm512_mask_i32logather_pd’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘_mm512_mask_i32gather_pd’?
```

Running the same code using icc with **-xCORE-AVX512** flag runs perfectly fine.

Is this because the GNU compiler doesn't support all the AVX512 instructions even though most of the instructions works perfectly fine by using **-mavx512f**  flag?

**Relevant information**

- gcc version - 11.2.0
- ubuntu version - 22.04
- icc version 2021.6.0

Comment: Is that intrinsic doing anything other than `_mm512_mask_i32gather_pd`?

Comment: @chtz No, the error message shows only '_mm512_mask_i32gather_pd'.

Answer (score 0):

GCC has intrinsics for all AVX-512 instructions.  It doesn't always have every alternate version of every intrinsic that differ only in their C semantics, not the underlying instruction they expose.

---

I think the only difference between the regular `_mm512_mask_i32gather_pd` intrinsic (which GCC supports) is that **`logather` takes a `__m512i vindex` instead of `__m256i`.  But uses only the low half**, hence the `lo` in the name.  (I looked at them in [the intrinsics guide](https://(https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,AVX_512,Other&ig_expand=6936,5239,5263,518,3951,3918,3951&text=vgatherdpd)) - same pseudocode, just a difference in C/C++ function signature.  And they're listed as intrinsics for the same single instruction).  There doesn't seem to be a `higather` intrinsic that includes a shuffle; you need to do the extracting yourself.

`vgatherdpd` gathers 8 `double` elements to fill a `__m512d`, using 32-bit indices.  The corresponding 8 indices are only a total of 32 bytes wide.  That's why the regular more widely-supported intrinsic only takes  a `__m256i vindex` arg.

Your code strangely bothers to initialize 64 bytes (16 indices), not shuffling the high half down.  Also you're merge-masking into `_mm512_undefined_pd()`, which seems a weird example.  But pretty obviously this isn't intended to be useful, since you're also loading *from* uninitialized `malloc`.  You're casting the result to a `__m512`, I guess using this instruction to gather pairs of `float` instead of individual `double`s?  If so, yeah it's more efficient to gather fewer elements, but it's a weird way to make a minimal simple example for an intrinsic you're looking for.  I wonder if **perhaps you were looking for `_mm512_mask_i32gather_ps` to gather 16x `float` elements**, merging into a `__m512` vector.  (The non-`_mask_` version gathers all 16 elements, and you don't have to supply a merge target; that's often what you want.)

---

**If you do have your 8 indices in a wider vector for some reason** (e.g. as a result of computation and you're going to do 2 gathers after shuffling), you can just cast the vector type:

```
  __m512i vindex = ...;  // the part we want is only the low half
  __m512d result = something to merge into;
 result = _mm512_mask_i32gather_pd(result, mask, _mm512_castsi512_si256(vindex),
                src_ptr, _MM_SCALE_8);
```

Your cast to `(float*)` in the arg list to the intrinsic makes no sense: it actually takes a `void*` so you can gather 64-bit chunks from anything (and yes it's strict-aliasing and alignment safe, not following C rules).  But the normal type would be `double*`, since this is a `_pd` gather.

In your example, it would be simpler to just `__m256 vindex = _mm256_setr_epi32(...);`  (Or `set`, if you like the highest-element-first order for the argument list.)